# iOS TabBar pushed up on keyboard appearance

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, keyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iOS8 app which has a UITabBarViewController as part of its master view. Embedded within that is a UITableViewController which has some UITextFields embedded in some of the cells.

When a text view is tapped, the keyboard automatically appears. If necessary, the 'view' is adjusted to allow the textView to remain showing so data can be entered.

The problem is that the tabBarController and associated tabs are also moved up. This is usually OK unless my phone is in landscape which leaves very little room to show the tableview and allow effective gestures (e.g. swiping the tableview up/down).

So, is there a way to get the keyboard to only push-up the tableview within the tabBarController, rather than the whole outer frame also being moved up? Picture below shows the problem. The device is in landscape

[image]

Comment: you found a way out?